# Unable to install texlive on Impish

Tags: apt, software-installation, latex

When I try to install the texlive distribution using:

> sudo apt install texlive

I get the following output:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree... Done Reading
> state information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This
> may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are
> using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
> yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following
> information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  texlive : Depends:
> texlive-latex-base (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not installable
> texlive-base : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2019.20190605)
> texlive-latex-recommended : Depends: texlive-binaries (>=
> 2019.20190605)
> Depends: texlive-latex-base (>= 2019.20200218) but it is not installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I have no idea what this means or how to fix it. Any gurus out there please help. I have run apt-get update successfully already.

Comment: Note that Impish will soon be out of support. Upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 (or fresh install). It will be supported until 2027.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have run `sudo apt update` to update the software database, install TeXLive with

```
sudo apt install texlive-full
```